# Using SMMRY to automatically generate a WordPress post summary

Tags: php, wordpress, smmry

I'm trying to automatically create a post summary using smmry when a WordPress post is saved.

This is my code:

```
function add_to_post( $args ) { 
$text = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$ch = curl_init("https://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=my-api-key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:")); // See Note
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sm_api_input=".$text);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$return = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$smmry = $return['sm_api_content'];
update_field('smmry', $smmry, $args['post_id']);
curl_close($ch);
}

add_action( 'save_post' , 'add_to_post' );
```

But it's not working, and it's not throwing any error messages so I don't know why.  $text is definitely fetching the post content.

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: How do I find out?

Comment: You can just print_r($smmry);

Comment: Okay, nothing shows up when I do that.

Comment: Any errors are displaying?

Comment: No, no errors are displaying.  Debug is set to true.

Comment: did you try this API `https://api.smmry.com/` call from postman?

Comment: No, I don't know what Postman is?

Comment: I think then this needs to more debug.